# How to inspect the session hash with Capybara and RSpec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, capybara, bdd

Found various posts about this on Stack Overflow, but didn't find a solution.

From within an integration test, how to inspect the session hash with Capybara and RSpec?

`puts session.inspect` throws an `undefined method for nil` error.

Comment: I think the answer will depend on driver you use with capybara. Selenium, capybara-webkit, PhantomJS or other?

Comment: I also believe that you should avoid dependency of session state in your integration tests, because it's not what user can see.

Comment: @cutalion - It's not for testing. It's for debugging - figuring out what is going on with the session when the behavior of the tests is unexpected.

Answer (score 3):

Based on [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12083296/how-to-inspect-the-session-hash-with-capybara-and-rspec#comment16165302_12083296) you need debugging so you can use:

```
save_and_open_page
```

to take a snapshot of a page and take a look at it, or you can use:

```
print page.html
```

if you want to retrieve the current state of the DOM as a string

Source: [Capybara debugging](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara#debugging)

Comment: Add "puts session.inspect" to the end of your view.