# possible to access session variables in Rspec with Capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

Is it possible to access session variables in Rspec with Capybara and Selenium drive?

How would I do something like this (I am using omniauth-facebook)?

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe 'Api' do
  def login_with_oauth
    visit "/auth/facebook"
  end

  it 'get location count for specific user' do
    login_with_oauth
    @user=User.find(session[:user_id])
    #puts "here is response body: #{response.body}"
```

I see 
[How to inspect the session hash with Capybara and RSpec?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12083296/how-to-inspect-the-session-hash-with-capybara-and-rspec) but doesn't get me what I really want.

thx

Answer (score 1):

I suppose to think what you actually don't need the session. I'm sorry if I'm wrong.

That's [how you can test](https://github.com/intridea/omniauth/wiki/Integration-Testing) omniauth.

```
# spec/spec_helper.rb
OmniAuth.config.test_mode = true
OmniAuth.config.mock_auth[:facebook] = OmniAuth::AuthHash.new
OmniAuth.config.add_mock(:facebook, {
  provider: "facebook",
  uid: "123456",
  info: {
    email: "bruce.wayne@batman.com",
    first_name: "Bruce",
    last_name: "Wayne"
  }
})


# spec/request/api_spec.rb
let!(:user) { create :user, email: "bruce.wayne@batman.com" }

before do
  visit "/auth/facebook"
end

it 'get location count for specific user' do
  user.id # contains your user id
end
```